# How do I make all the button squeeze together to the left side on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I make all the button squeeze together on the left side on flutter? Now they are just evenly spread out.

[image]

```
  Widget _selectDayBar() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        _dayBar("Mon"),
        _dayBar("Tue"),
        _dayBar("Wed"),
        _dayBar("Thu"),
        _dayBar("Fri"),
        _dayBar("Sat"),
        _dayBar("Sun"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Spacer()` to the end of your `children`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `crossAxisAlignment` property and set its value to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`

```
Widget _selectDayBar() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // this right here
    children: <Widget>[
      _dayBar("Mon"),
      _dayBar("Tue"),
      _dayBar("Wed"),
      _dayBar("Thu"),
      _dayBar("Fri"),
      _dayBar("Sat"),
      _dayBar("Sun"),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change to "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start"
Here is more reference for you: https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone! i fix it by using a spacer.

[image]

```
 Widget _selectDayBar() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // this right here
      children: <Widget>[
        _dayBar("Mon"),
        _dayBar("Tue"),
        _dayBar("Wed"),
        _dayBar("Thu"),
        _dayBar("Fri"),
        _dayBar("Sat"),
        _dayBar("Sun"),
        Spacer(flex: 2),
        // Spacer(),
        // Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
```